# Display values from array if is in array

Tags: php, arrays

Sorry I'm not into php and I've some issues to find something in array and if its founded display full row with that array.

Probably is dead simple but I can't find solution

Code must be compatible with php 5.2

```
if (isset($_POST)) {

    $companies = [
        ['label' => 'Sandwich', 'campaign' => 12, 'variant' => '1a'],
        ['label' => 'Burgers', 'campaign' => 13, 'variant' => '1b'],
        ['label' => 'Bread', 'campaign' => 14, 'variant' => '1c'],
        ['label' => 'Coke', 'campaign' => 15, 'variant' => '1d'],
        ['label' => 'Pepsi', 'campaign' => 16, 'variant' => '1e'],
        ['label' => 'Fanta', 'campaign' => 17, 'variant' => '1f'],
        ['label' => 'Pepper', 'campaign' => 18, 'variant' => '1g']

    ];

    $code = $_POST['code'];
    $codeST = strtoupper($code);
    $ar = array_column($companies, 'label');

    if (in_array($codeST, $ar)) {
        $campaign = "Campaign value for founded label";
        $variant = "Variant value for founded label";
        echo json_encode('{"status":"Ok","label": "' . $code . '", "campaign": "' . $campaign . '", "variant": "' . $variant . '"}');

    } else {
        echo json_encode('{"status":"No"}');
    }
}
```

Need display value for campaign and variant if label is the same as posted value

Comment: What errors/issues are you facing? What is your expected output?

Comment: I've no errors so far I just want to display row if label is the same as request

Comment: `Code must be compatible with php 5.2` means you can't use short hand array notation. e.g. `$companies = [` must become `$companies = array(`

Comment: Your `json_encode` also is going to double encode the JSON. Is that intended?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `in_array`, which just returns a true/false result, use [`array_search`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to get the key corresponding to the value (if it does exist). Then you can use that as an index to get the `campaign` and `variant` values.

```
$code = $_POST['code'];
$codeST = ucfirst(strtolower($code));
$ar = array_column($companies, 'label');
if (($key = array_search($codeST, $ar)) !== false) {
    $campaign = $companies[$key]['campaign'];
    $variant = $companies[$key]['variant'];
    echo '{"status":"Ok","label": "' . $codeST . '", "campaign": "' . $campaign . '", "variant": "' . $variant . '"}';

} else {
    echo '{"status":"No"}';
}
```

**Notes:**

1. `array_search` returns `false` if it does not find the value.
2. Your strings are already JSON, you don't need to
   `json_encode` them as well. I have removed those calls...
3. Based on the labels in your `$companies` array, you should be using `ucfirst(strtolower($code))`, not `strtoupper($code)`

If `$_POST['code'] = 'BReAd'`, this code will output:

```
{"status":"Ok","label": "Bread", "campaign": "14", "variant": "1c"}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/AEQ7G)

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through $companies to match label and then access related data, here is solution.
    if (isset($_POST)) {

```
  $companies = [
    ['label' => 'Sandwich', 'campaign' => 12, 'variant' => '1a'],
    ['label' => 'Burgers', 'campaign' => 13, 'variant' => '1b'],
    ['label' => 'Bread', 'campaign' => 14, 'variant' => '1c'],
    ['label' => 'Coke', 'campaign' => 15, 'variant' => '1d'],
    ['label' => 'Pepsi', 'campaign' => 16, 'variant' => '1e'],
    ['label' => 'Fanta', 'campaign' => 17, 'variant' => '1f'],
    ['label' => 'Pepper', 'campaign' => 18, 'variant' => '1g']

  ];

  $code = $_POST['code'];
  $codeST = strtoupper($code);
  foreach ($companies as $company){
    if($company['label']==$codeST){
      $campaign = $company['campaign'];
      $variant = $company['variant'];
      echo json_encode('{"status":"Ok","label": "' . $code . '", "campaign": "' . $campaign . '", "variant": "' . $variant . '"}');
    } else {
      echo json_encode('{"status":"No"}');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've an error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /in/bE3e8 on line 2